# O que é e o que faz um full stack web developer?

Tags: terminologia

Estive procurando a respeito desse termo e não compreendi muito bem a função desse profissional de TI. O que é um *"full stack web developer"*?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

É aquele que lida tanto com o *back-end* (o lado dos servidores), quanto com o *front-end* (o lado dos clientes, os browsers).

O *back-end* envolve ao menos uma linguagem de programação, e geralmente um banco de dados (que costuma ser SQL, mas pode ser de outro tipo, noSQL ou pares de chave-valor). O *front-end* envolve HTML, CSS e JavaScript (bem como outras ferramentas e frameworks ligadas a essas tecnologias).

O conjunto todo é chamado de "stack", pois se trata de uma "pilha" de tecnologias (pense nas tecnologias do servidor embaixo, e as do cliente em cima). Então "full-stack" é aquele desenvolvedor que lida com todas as camadas da pilha, e não só com uma parte delas.

Encontrei um [artigo no SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-stack-developer/) em que o autor conta como é ser um desenvolvedor *full stack* atualmente, inclusive listando muitas das tecnologias com que você pode ter de lidar. Ele inclui a seguinte ilustração das camadas de desenvolvimento:

[image: Ilustração das camadas de desenvolvimento web]

<sup>A figura pode dar a entender que quanto mais voltado para o servidor, mais árida é a vida do desenvolvedor, enquanto do lado do cliente tudo é lindo e os cãezinhos passeiam felizes num dia ensolarado. Mas a realidade não é bem assim não :)</sup>

Comment: Lembrando que isso interfere diretamente no desempenho de uma equipe, profissionais full-stack geralmente estão sobrecarregados fazendo com que a eficiencia deles caia bastante.

Comment: O @RodrigoBorth tem razão, mas acho que vale a pena diferenciar um profissional com atribuições em todo esse intervalo de um que saiba atuar nele. Ou seja, eu creio que a expressão também pode ser utilizada para se referir a um profissional capacitado (isto é, com conhecimento formal e experiência prática) em diversas tecnologias de cada camada.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Eu me considero um profissional full-stack, embora nem sempre precise lidar com todas as camadas. Mas não tenho certeza se esse é o motivo de eu viver sobrecarregado...

Comment: P.S.: O gato ali do lado esquerdo tá tunadão em cafeína. Deve ter virado a noite programando... :)

Comment: @LuizVieira E quem será o cachorro? Talvez o usuário. Porque não parece bravo o suficiente para ser o cliente ou o chefe :)

Comment: Se ele tivesse carregando um galho de árvore entre os dentes ([*playing fetch!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch_%28game%29)) eu ia dizer que ele era um *stakeholder* (ba.dum.tss!). Poxa, era piada pronta, vai! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto se você anda sobrecarregado, realmente pode ser por trabalhar *full stack*, mas talvez a causa do seu *stack overflow* seja outra ;)

Comment: Talvez o profissional full-stack fique sobrecarregado
mas a fragmentação leva a uma Via unica de pensamento, a inovação vem quando temos a junção de conhecimentos prévios, claro que isso da para fazer com mais de uma pessoa, mas é muito limitado.

full-stack  é excelente para gerenciar equipes, scrum-master.
um bom exemplo de divisão não funcional rs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg

Comment: @Bacco Parte da causa é o próprio Stack Overflow, sem dúvida!

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes Já estive em muitas reuniões assim, rs!

Comment: @bfavaretto, idem, trabalhei em uma equipe que era considerada "experts" então esse tipo de reunião era bem comum, full-stack é a melhor alternativa em projetos novos, onde não sabe onde exatamente queremos chegar.

Comment: Muito bom senhores; discussão de pessoas inteligentes é outro nível. Parabéns a todos vocês!

Comment: Eu me considero um *full-stack developer* com ênfase em *back-end*. Isso significa que geralmente eu consigo entender como o front-end funciona e opinar como isso deve ser, além de atuar temporariamente no front-end quando necessário. Isso **não** significa que trabalhe em ambos back e front num mesmo projeto, muito menos ao mesmo tempo. Pela minha experiência, um "full stack" ou algo parecido é necessário em algum momento caso contrário vai haver dificuldades de comunicação e prioridades entre desenvolvedores back-end e front-end.

Comment: Só tem uma coisa que falou nesta resposta: colocar o diabo com um tridente, fogo e muita bagunça abaixo daquela camada marrom ali. :)

Comment: Então um **bom** freelancer, em geral, é um desenvolvedor _full stack_? Já que além de lidar com back e front ele também lida com diversas outras coisas (gerenciamento de projeto, captador e interpretador do cliente, etc)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Em geral, sim – acho.

Answer (score 27):

*Full stack web developer* é um perfil de desenvolvedor que consegue trabalhar não somente com um determinado tipo de programação mas também compreender de forma razoável uma porção de outras tecnologias envolvidas em um sistema: banco de dados, infra-estrutura, sistema operacional, servidor web, rede, CSS/HTML, Javascript, etc.

Estes profissionais conseguem **solucionar uma grande gama de problemas** deste "stack" todo e, quando precisam de ajuda, precisam de pouca instrução de um profissional especialista na referida tecnologia para conseguirem prosseguir sozinhos. Profissionais com este perfil são também muito valorizados por conta **facilitarem a comunicação entre as diferentes áreas** que participam de um projeto, uma vez que entende bem um pouco de cada, funcionando como um [intermediador](https://hackernoon.com/6-essential-tips-on-how-to-become-a-full-stack-developer-1d10965aaead) e agilizando as soluções.

Ao contrário do que é pensado, não é preciso ser um desenvolvedor experiente para considerar-se "full stack". Isto pode ocorrer perfeitamente nos primeiros anos do profissional, basta o mesmo ter contato com estas diferentes tecnologias, o que normalmente ocorre em empresas menores, *startups* (onde nem sempre há um profissional dedicado para cada tecnologia) ou empresas que valorizam este tipo de profissional.

Answer (score 13):

Não há uma definição formal para este termo, há visões diferentes sobre os limites de atribuições e até criticismo por parte de alguns. A definição mais comumente aceita é a descrita pela resposta do @bfavaretto. Porém, há muito debate sobre o assunto na internet.

Não raro, empresas requerem que um full-stack developer atue não somente com desenvolvimento back-end + front-end. Infra-estrutura, QA, análise de negócio e interação com o cliente entram para o rol de responsabilidades do desenvolvedor. Essa visão é compartilhada por diversos desenvolvedores.

Com o debate sobre as atribuições de um full-stack developer, defende-se que o full-stack developer abrange todas (ou quase todas) etapas de desenvolvimento de software.

---

Leitura adicional:

- http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/08/what-is-a-full-stack-developer
- http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/04/full-stack-developers.html
- https://medium.com/swlh/the-full-stack-developer-is-a-myth-4e3fb9c25867

Answer (score -1):

Esse termo descreve aqueles que possuem a facilidade de compreender os varios aspectos a nivel de tecnologias que constituem um sistema, quer sejam do lado do cliente quer do lado do servidor.