# Como uma página de erro (404) deve se comportar?

Tags: ux, http-status-404

Ela deve redirecionar para outra página? Depois de quanto tempo?

Deve ter um índice? Uma caixa e busca livre? Ou já fazer a busca sugerindo páginas baseado no que foi digitado?

Ela deve demonstrar que é um erro? Deve mostrar o 404? Ou é melhor algo mais limpo e parecer algo normal e que apenas precisa fazer outra coisa?

A página deve manter o *design* do site ou ter algo neutro? Deve ser bem limpa ou com o máximo de informação possível? Deve aproveitar para mais alguma coisa? Publicidade?

O erro pode ser do site ou do usuário que digitou algo errado, ou mesmo de quem colocou um *link* errado para ele, então pode ser de terceiros. Esse é um caso concreto para [pedir desculpas ou não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/101)?

Enfim, o que tem que ser observado na página 404?

Este pergunta já foi feita no [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/84856/1490). Eu queria uma resposta mais adequada para nossa cultura. Note que as respostas lá foram bem objetivas. Faça o mesmo aqui. Só responda se souber fundamentar, mesmo que seja pela sua experiência, mas precisa do fundamento.

Comment: Alguma das resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitar alguma delas agora? Seu *feedback* é muito importante para a comunidade.

Comment: @Stormwind ainda vou ver o que fazer, talvez eu coloque recompensa, mas no feriado é complicado.

Comment: Sem problemas. Se precisar de mais informações basta editar a pergunta e/ou comentar os pontos a serem melhorados.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Talvez infelizmente, o erro é clássico. O [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) o define assim:

> a resposta HTTP que indica que o cliente se comunicou com o servidor, mas o servidor não pode encontrar o que lhe foi requisitado

seja por um link compartilhado errado por terceiros ou um link em sua própria página que não exista mais.

#### A página deve redirecionar para outra página?

A página requisitada não existe mais ou mesmo nunca existiu. Não há sentido em redirecionar o utilizador para alguma outra página. Ele acessou a página X porque quer consumir o conteúdo que procurava em X, não em Y ou até XY.

O que você pode fazer é dar opções de conteúdos similares, como abordo mais para frente, em "A página deve ter um campo de busca?".

Como apontado pelo [@Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss), se por ventura você sabe qual é a página que seu cliente queria ir - isso acontecerá caso a página tenha sido movida, retorno HTTP 301 - redirecione sem mostrar a página de erro, que é mais conveniente. Pense como um bloco `catch`, você trata o erro e em algumas situações não deixa isso claro para o utilizador. Isso acontece com os aviões a todo o tempo durante seu voo, módulos e sub-módulos param de funcionar e outros assumem.

"Tratar o erro é melhor que mostrá-lo" é uma das [10 heurísticas da usabilidade](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/). Recomendo a leitura de ["Preventing User Errors: Avoiding Unconscious Slips"](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/slips/) de Page Laubheimer, especialista em UX da Nielsen Norman Group, uma consultoria estadunidense de UI e experiência do usuário.

#### A página deve ter um campo de busca?

Esse ponto foca em dar uma alternativa para quem acessa. Se um restaurante não tem mais o camarão ao molho alfredo que você costuma pedir, que resposta é mais amigável?

1. Não temos mais esse prato.
2. Não temos mais esse prato, mas o que acha do camarão ao molho branco?

Como consumidor, eu prefiro ter uma opção similar, vou com a dois.

Disponha um link para a página inicial ou um campo de busca. Ou os dois! Que for que seja, uma página que informa um erro mas não dá qualquer tentativa de solução ou escape fere a experiência do usuário.

Se você consegue saber a intenção do usuário, como no caso do camarão, e tiver o campo de busca, preencha o campo com algo relevante à intenção. Por vezes é inútil o usuário acessar `https://www.maniero.com.br/qwe8jas0` (a página correta era `/qwe8jas1`) e você preencher o campo de busca com `qwe8jas0`.

Nesse caso, seria interessante repensar sua estrutura de links para algo mais amigável, como `https://www.maniero.com.br/blog/csharp/tratando-erros` e preencher a busca com `tratando erros` talvez.

Além de preencher a busca pode adicionar links como:

- Procurando algum blog?
- Procurando conteúdo de C#?

Já que você reconhece que seu site possui `/blog` e `/blog/csharp`.

É claro, tudo isso se for possível. Às vezes ele seguiu um link totalmente ininteligível ou um link encurtado como `https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/84856/106770`.

Pode utilizar dos subdomínios também. Se eu estou em `office.microsoft.com` e acesso uma página que não exista, um link aparece dizendo "procurando produtos do Office?". [Veja em ação.](https://products.office.com/pt-br/mac/microsoft-office-faor-mac?WT.mc_id=oan_mscom_prog_mac_targeted)

- [justinmind: "6 best practices for 404 pages with killer UX"](https://www.justinmind.com/blog/6-best-practices-for-404-pages-with-killer-ux/)

#### A página deve demonstrar que é um erro?

Sim, a página deve demonstrar que é um erro. Mas dependendo do seu público ela não precisa ser tão clara a ponto de mostrar o código 404. Veja alguns exemplos:

- Não é possível encontrar a página solicitada. A página que você está procurando não está disponível no mercado para a sua região ou não existe mais. [(retirado da loja do MS Office)](https://products.office.com/pt-br/mac/microsoft-office-faor-mac?WT.mc_id=oan_mscom_prog_mac_targeted)
- A página que você está procurando não foi encontrada. [campo de busca]. Ou veja o mapa do site. [(retirado da apple.com/br)](https://www.apple.com/br/404)
- Procurando alguma coisa? Desculpe, mas a página que você digitou não existe no nosso site. Acesse a Página Inicial da Amazon.com.br [(retirado da Amazon)](https://www.amazon.com.br/404)
- Oops! Parece que perdemos a sua página. Desculpe, nós não conseguimos achar a página que você estava procurando. Por que não faz uma busca rápida para ser se nós podemos achar a informação que você estava procurando? [campo de busca]. [mapa do site em forma de mapa de metrô].  [(retirado de hallaminternet.com)](https://www.hallaminternet.com/404/)

Jakob Nielsen, autor de diversos livros de usabilidade e UX, definiu, em 1990, heurísticas para o design de interfaces, em [Heuristic evaluation of user interfaces](http://scholar.google.com.br/scholar_url?url=https://sites.google.com/a/upou.edu.ph/learningresources/files/NielsenandMolich-1990-Heuristicevaluationofuserinterfaces.pdf&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm36vtzULJl-TmPFJOvrsM-i7GvCbg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr&ved=0ahUKEwiL1MXLtOnWAhUBHpAKHak1D-wQgAMIJSgAMAA) (não clique no link se não quiser fazer o download do artigo pelo Google Scholar). Ele defende a clareza do andamento e status em que a aplicação se encontra.

Em 1995, para reforçar as heurísticas definidas por ele, [Nielsen publica](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

> as mensagens de erros devem ser expressadas em linguagem simples (sem códigos) e precisa para indicar o problema, e construtivamente sugerir uma solução.

Em contra partida, ao trabalhar com um público técnico, como desenvolvedores, o código de erro pode ajudar a indicar o problema e também levar o mesmo à um certo caminho. Um bom exemplo é a [MSDN](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/404), portal de desenvolvimento da Microsoft, que utiliza nas suas páginas 404 o erro explícito.

#### A página deve manter o design do site ou ter algo neutro?

Mantenha o seu padrão. A discrepância entre o [site da Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.br) e a [página de erro](https://www.amazon.com.br/404) deixa isso claro. Se não fosse pelo logotipo eu diria que estava em outro site.

Deixe claro que algo aconteceu e a página não foi encontrada, dê alternativas e só. Dê uma pausa nos anúncios e deixe que o usuário encontrar seu caminho ali.

- [uxdesign.cc: "Design principle: Consistency"](https://uxdesign.cc/design-principle-consistency-6b0cf7e7339f)
- [UX Booth: "Consistency: Key to a Better UX"](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/consistency-key-to-a-better-user-experience/)

#### Esse é um caso concreto para pedir desculpas ou não?

O cliente já está frustrado pois talvez não conseguirá mais achar o conteúdo que estava interessado ou algo semelhante. Dependendo do seu público sua página pode ser até [um pouco mais humorística](https://github.com/404). Se for mais formal, peça desculpas ou lamente o ocorrido ("infelizmente"). Seja direto e forneça uma maneira de contatar o desenvolvedor para que haja uma possível solução.

#### E como deve ser minha página?

1. [**Consistente.**](https://uxdesign.cc/design-principle-consistency-6b0cf7e7339f) Mantenha seu padrão de layout.
2. [**Clara.**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) Seja claro com o usuário do que está acontecendo,
   sem incluir códigos de erro ou dados técnicos explicitamente se eles
   não adicionam nada ao seu público.
3. [**Alternativa.**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) Não seja genérico, trate o problema dando
   opções de conteúdo similar ao que usuário requeriu por meio de links e um campo de busca.
4. [**Mínima.**](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/effective-minimalism-in-experience-design/) Aproveite o espaço para o que importa, apresente o que é relevante e corte a superfluidade.
5. [**Facilmente visualizável.**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/) Evite o scroll, deixe seu conteúdo ser visualizado com desígnio e praticidade.

Veja um fragmento de uma página 404 do StackOverflow em Português.

> [image]

Ela dá muitas opções, forma de contato com desenvolvedores, é limpa e direta. Como trabalha com um público técnico, deixa claro o código HTTP 404 (não está na imagem pois iria ficar muito grande)

Comment: Ao meu entender, a resposta pareceu um pouco contraditória em alguns pontos - ou só não muito claros. Acredito que o redirecionamento de página só seja interessante quando o servidor responder com *301 Moved Permanently*, mas não com *404*. No geral, acho que se for possível inferir sobre o que o usuário tentou acessar o ideal realmente seria apenas sugerir os possíveis links, visto que só teríamos a certeza absoluta na resposta HTTP 301.

Comment: Feita a edição. Obrigado. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 8):

Primeiro, acredito que seja interessante definir o que é e para que serve uma mensagem de erro.

De acordo com os [dicionários confiáveis da língua portuguesa](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/304), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/erro), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=erro) e [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/erro) um erro, sintetizadamente, seria:

> Aquilo que resulta de uma má compreensão ou de análise deficiente de um fato ou de um assunto. Engano, incorreção ou inexatidão.
> Conceituação imprecisa de uma ideia ou interpretação falha de um assunto, de um tema; inexatidão.
> Falta de correção, de exatidão, de perfeição etc.; Falha; Defeito; Imperfeição.

Sobre propósito de uma mensagem de erro, a seguinte definição cabe bem:

> **A finalidade de uma mensagem de erro é ajudar o usuário que encontrou o erro, a aprender como evitar o comportamento que causou o problema**. O programa encontrou uma situação que não pode manipular e precisa dizer ao usuário, de modo que o usuário (ou outra pessoa) entenda e possa evitar a situação que o programa não pode manipular. [...] Mensagem de erro genéricas que dizem: "ocorreu um erro inesperado" é totalmente inútil nesse objetivo. Dá ao usuário nenhuma sugestão sobre o que pode ser alterado para evitar o problema, ou até mesmo corrigir esse problema.

Entendendo essa definição, é possível estabelecer três pontos importantes para uma boa mensagem de erro:

- Informar qual é o problema.
- Fazer você se sentir como se houvesse algo que você pudesse fazer sobre isso.
- Falar como um humano e ser uma extensão consistente da personalidade do resto da aplicação.

---

## Fazer um redirecionamento para outra página?

> Ela deve redirecionar para outra página? Depois de quanto tempo?

Em linhas gerais, não é recomendado que redirecione o usuário para outra página, principalmente se for para uma página fora do seu domínio. O principal motivo é que você nunca sabe ao certo para onde o usuário realmente quer ir.

> Se o usuário estiver tentando acessar uma URL antiga que foi movida, é bom redirecioná-los para a URL antiga e informar que houve uma mudança de endereço, e **então dar a opção** de seguir o link para a nova página. Mas **você realmente deveria estar usando um redirecionamento 3xx em vez de um 404**.

Os códigos de erro HTTP, nunca devem ser trocados e/ou mal utilizados. Imagine se você for fazer manutenção em uma página que está retornando erro 500 (Erro de Servidor Interno), enquanto na verdade, o erro real é o 403 (Acesso Negado). A menos que você seja vidente, e peço desculpas se for, como você vai descobrir de onde veio o erro e como vai corrigí-lo?

## Deixa uma caixa de busca?

> Deve ter um índice? Uma caixa e busca livre? Ou já fazer a busca sugerindo páginas baseado no que foi digitado?

Depende de que tipo de aplicação e o público alvo está sendo tratado. Em casos mais comuns, é interessante você deixar uma caixa para pesquisa livre. Sobretudo se você já tem uma barra de navegação fixa com uma caixa de pesquisa (como no caso do [Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2445641/java)) que irá mostrar mais links sugerindo outros locais, é desnecessário fazer ambos.

Nesses casos, adotar uma página mostrando tópicos relacionados é vantajoso. Pode não ser a alternativa mais amigável em questões de UX ([alguns concordam, outros discordam](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84856/best-practices-to-design-a-404-error-page#comment135352_84875)), mas como no caso do Stack Overflow que mantém a barra de navegação constantemente em todas páginas, a opção de sugestões de páginas é algo a se considerar.

## Mostrar o erro explicitamente?

> Ela deve demonstrar que é um erro? Deve mostrar o 404? Ou é melhor algo mais limpo e parecer algo normal e que apenas precisa fazer outra coisa?

É proveitoso mostrar o número 404, pelos seguintes motivos:

- Ele é um *shorthand* para o erro. O número 404 já sintetiza uma mensagem de erro;
- A grande maioria das pessoas sabem o que significa o que é 404, mesmo que de maneira simplificada;

**Demonstrar o erro é a melhor opção**. Já é de conhecimento público que fugir dos problemas, não é a melhor alternativa (tanto na vida, quanto na programação). O problema simplesmente cresce, vira uma bola de neve e só vai gerar mais dores de cabeça. Tem até frases falando disso:

> Não fuja de seus problemas nem se desespere. Encare-os de frente com coragem e determinação, pois se não resolvê-los no dia de hoje, certamente terá que fazê-lo no dia de amanhã porque eles continuarão existindo enquanto não forem resolvidos, prolongando o seu sofrimento.

<sup>Fonte: [Pensador](https://www.pensador.com/frases_fugir_dos_problemas/)</sup>

Resumidamente, já falei sobre isso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245345/66203):

> [...] De maneira sintetizada, explique o mínimo para seu usuário, mas de maneira clara e compreensível, e se possível faça algo que permita ao usuário saber que o problema não está sendo ignorado. Deixe-os tomar alguma ação, como enviar os logs ou enviar um relatório de erro. Alternativamente, deixe-os saber que a ação automática já foi tomada e que seu pessoal técnico foi notificado automaticamente de que esse erro ocorreu e está trabalhando nisso.[...]

## Como deve ser o *design* da página de erro?

> A página deve manter o *design* do site ou ter algo neutro? Deve ser bem limpa ou com o máximo de informação possível? Deve aproveitar para mais alguma coisa? Publicidade?

O trecho supracitado já cobre uma parte do questionamento:

> [...] De maneira sintetizada, explique o mínimo para seu usuário, mas de maneira clara e compreensível, e se possível faça algo que permita ao usuário saber que o problema não está sendo ignorado. Deixe-os tomar alguma ação, como enviar os logs ou enviar um relatório de erro. Alternativamente, deixe-os saber que a ação automática já foi tomada e que seu pessoal técnico foi notificado automaticamente de que esse erro ocorreu e está trabalhando nisso.[...]

Mantenha o *design* no padrão do seu site e a mensagem de erro de maneira simples e compreensível. Alguns motivos para seguir essa ideia são:

- Seu usuário não é um *expert* em erros, ou um [*full stack web developer*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52450/66203), então retornar todo o [código de erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzmYp.jpg), e/ou a [pilha de erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fen06.jpg) não faz nenhum sentido (em casos de erros extras).

O erro deve ser mostrado para quem vai resolver o problema. É o usuário? Não! Então não mostre pra ele o que ele não vai resolver. Mostre uma mensagem de erro mínima, completa e compreensível, que informe o porque e se ele pode fazer alguma coisa para colaborar.

- Se você mudar muito o design da página de erro, seu usuário pode pensar que clicou em algum link indevido, e foi redirecionado para algum site de terceiros.

Tente manter a coesão entre as páginas de erro com o resto do seu site. Seja uma extensão consistente da personalidade do resto da aplicação. E por favor, sem publicidades quando está ocorrendo erro. Fazendo isso, o usuário poderia facilmente pensar: "Tem tempo para colocar anúncios, mas não resolve essa porcaria".

- De maneira alternativa, tente entender que quando o usuário mais leigo, vê uma mensagem de erro, a primeira coisa que ele procura, quase sempre, é o botão fechar (é incrível). Você pode dar 2 linhas de mensagem, ou todo um *stack trace*, e mesmo assim, haverão usuários que não irão ler.

Quer um exemplo disso? Tenho certeza que nem metade das pessoas do próprio [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) sabe de cabeça o que aparece escrito no *modal* que aparece quando você clica no botão <kbd>Responder à sua pergunta</kbd> (eu sei que você olhou agora para ver o que tinha escrito). Então, por essas e outras, pode ver que não há motivos para informar vários códigos "*estranhos*" e "*inúmeras linhas de erro*".

## Vale a pena fazer um pedido de desculpa?

> O erro pode ser do site ou do usuário que digitou algo errado, ou mesmo de quem colocou um link errado para ele, então pode ser de terceiros. Esse é um caso concreto para pedir desculpas ou não?

**Peça desculpas**. O usuário está acessando seu site, sua responsabilidade. Imagine a seguinte situação: Você vai na padaria e não tem pão, por qualquer motivo que seja, desde a máquina ter quebrado, acabou a energia, o padeiro quebrou a perna, não tinha mais fermento, ou não houve uma safra descente, e não houve maneiras de fazer farinha. O dono da padaria, vai dizer:

> Me desculpe, mas aconteceu XYZ, e então blá, blá, blá...

Além de ser uma questão de educação (é bom e eu gosto, e acredito que você goste também), você estará mostrando que se importa com o usuário. Existe também um trecho da excelente resposta sobre o [apropriado pedido de desculpa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/66203) que diz:

> [...] O fato é que a desculpa é um lubrificante social importante, cujo caráter na interação serve também como forma de indicar a real intenção do interlocutor (algo como "eu realmente não quis te machucar/incomodar de propósito"), e por isso é tradicionalmente utilizada para iniciar uma conversação considerando uma possível interrupção de qualquer introspecção/atividade do destinatário da mensagem [...]

Veja que quando você pede desculpas, você está "preparando a atmosfera" da interação, o que ainda possibilita, nesse caso, oferecer outros produtos ao seu cliente (assim como o dono da padaria faz). Se fosse o caso, ele diria algo como: "Não temos X hoje, mas que tal levar um saboroso Y e/ou Z. Também temos disponível A e B se quiser".

#### Concluindo

Depois dessas considerações, acredito que possa dar uma olhada também nessas páginas de erro 404, que exemplificam o que foi dito nesta resposta:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/v3/troubleshooting)
- [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1121564/error)
- [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831363(v=wsasfasdf415)dsf)
- [Blizzard Entertainment](http://us.blizzard.com/pt-br/404abc)

Perceba que todas, implementa  quase tudo que foi dito. Possuem pedidos de desculpa, informações sintetizadas, caixa de pesquisa, e a convenção padrão de uso. Lógico que não existe uma página de erro UX perfeita. A lógica de cada página varia bastante com o seu público alvo e a filosofia dos desenvolvedores. Mas em linhas gerais elas seguem a sabedoria convencional e as "*boas práticas*".

Answer (score 1):

**Sobre o 404:**

- Bom, digamos que o [código 404](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) é apenas um codigo de resposta do protocolo HTTP que notifica sistemas e API's sobre uma busca inválida dentro daquele sistema. (**TL; DR:** Endereço URL errado dentro daquele dominio). Existem vários outros códigos, e possuem o único intuito de ajudar o programador a tratar exceções sobre a aplicação.

**Minha visão sobre as páginas:**

A maioria dos sites aproveita este status code e exibem páginas com esse código de erro para seus clientes caso a URL acessada esteja incorreta.

- Na minha visão é necessário que exista um texto breve e claro do possivel erro. Além disso não faça redirects e mantenha a estrutura do site, porquê é importante que o usuario saiba onde e o porquê do erro. (Deixar uma busca fácil ou mesmo criar um mecanismo que faça uma sugestão por palavras relacionadas aquela URL é uma solução válida também)

**Exemplos:**

- usuario tentou acessar site.com/home mas acessou site.com/hoem
- usuario tentou acessar uma página que não existe mais.

**Notas:**

É comum também, ver o uso de páginas de manutenção do site (caso o mesmo esteja fora do ar devido a algum erro, problema ou mesmo uma manutenção). Nesta página sim você deve explicar de maneira genérica sobre o problema e tentar redirecionar para a mesma requisição falha por várias e várias vezes.